A theorem on page 72 in The Large Scale Structure of Space-Time
In chapter 3 of the book, page 72, a static observer is defined as $V^{a}\equiv f^{-1}K^{a}$, where $K^{a}$ is a timelike Killing vector field and $f^{2}=-K^{a}K_{a}$. Then, Hawking & Ellis claim that $\nabla_{b}V^{a}=-V_{b}A^{a}$, where $\nabla_{b}$ denotes the covariant derivative and $A^{a}=V^{b}\nabla_{b}V^{a}=f^{-1}\nabla^{a}f$ is the four-acceleration. I wonder how to prove that $\nabla_{b}V^{a}=-V_{b}A^{a}$ ?

You didn’t mention the most important part of the definition of staticity, which is that $K$ must be “hypersurface orthogonal”, or in other words, the subbundle $\mathcal{K}:=\text{span}(K)\subset TM$ is such that the orthogonal complement $\mathcal{K}^{\perp}$ is integrable in the sense of Frobenius’ theorem.
Let’s start from the beginning. Let $K$ be any timelike Killing vector field. Then, almost by definition, $\nabla K$ is skew-adjoint relative to the metric, i.e for all vector fields $X,Y$, we have $g(\nabla_XK,Y)=-g(X,\nabla_YK)$; in components, this simply expresses $\nabla_aK_b=-\nabla_bK_a$. Next, let us define the unit vector $V:=\frac{K}{f}$, where $f:=\sqrt{-g(K,K)}$. Then, we have $g(V,V)=-1$, and so for any vector field $X$, we have
\begin{align}
2g(\nabla_XV,V)&=0,\tag{1}
\end{align}
i.e the values of $\nabla V$ are always orthogonal to $V$ (and hence to $K$). In particular, the acceleration $A:=\nabla_VV$ is orthogonal to $V$ (this is the natural generalization of the basic fact that a particle undergoing uniform circular motion experiences a purely centripetal acceleration, i.e the acceleration is orthogonal to the velocity).
Now, let $X,Y$ be any vector fields, and decompose them into components parallel to $V$ and orthogonal to $V$:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
X&=-g(X,V)V+\xi\\
Y&=-g(Y,V)V+\eta.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then, we have
\begin{align}
g(\nabla_XV,Y)&=0+g(\nabla_XV,\eta)\\
&=g(\nabla_{-g(X,V)V+\xi}V,\eta)\\
&=-g(X,V)g(\nabla_VV,\eta)+g(\nabla_{\xi}V,\eta)\\
&=-g(X,V)g(A,\eta)+g(\nabla_{\xi}V,\eta)\\
&=-g(X,V)g(A,Y)+g(\nabla_{\xi}V,\eta),\tag{2}
\end{align}
where in the first and last equal signs, I used that $\nabla V$ has values orthogonal to $V$, and so its inner product with $Y$ is the same as that with $\eta$. The first term on the RHS looks promising, so we just have to deal with the second term.
For the second term of $(2)$, just write out $V=\frac{K}{f}$, and use the product rule:
\begin{align}
g(\nabla_{\xi}V,\eta)&=g\left(-\frac{\nabla_{\xi}f}{f^2}K+\frac{\nabla_{\xi}K}{f},\eta\right)=0+\frac{1}{f}g(\nabla_{\xi}K,\eta),\tag{3}
\end{align}
where once again the $0$ is because $\eta$ is orthogonal to $V$ (and hence to $K$). Now, for any vector fields $\xi,\eta$ orthogonal to $V$ (and hence to $K$), we have
\begin{align}
g(\nabla_{\xi}K,\eta)&=\nabla_{\xi}\bigg(g(K,\eta)\bigg)-g(\xi,\nabla_{\xi}\eta)\\
&=0-g(K,\nabla_{\xi}\eta)\\
&=-g(K,\nabla_{\eta}\xi+[\xi,\eta])\tag{$\nabla$ is torsion-free}\\
&=-g(K,\nabla_{\eta}\xi)-g(K,[\xi,\eta])\\
&=g(\nabla_{\eta}K,\xi)-g(K,[\xi,\eta]),
\end{align}
where the final equal sign follows by interchanging the roles of $\xi,\eta$ in the second equal sign. So, rearranging gives $g(\nabla_{\xi}K,\eta)-g(\nabla_{\eta}K,\xi)=-g(K,[\xi,\eta])$, and since $K$ is Killing, we can exploit the skew-adjointness of $\nabla K$ to rewrite this as
\begin{align}
2g(\nabla_{\xi}K,\eta)&=-g(K,[\xi,\eta]).\tag{4}
\end{align}
Hence, plugging $(4)$ into $(3)$ and then $(3)$ into $(2)$ gives
\begin{align}
g(\nabla_XV,Y)&=-g(V,X)g(A,Y)-\frac{1}{2f}g(K,[\xi,\eta]).\tag{$5$}
\end{align}
Finally, at this stage, if we assume the subbundle $\mathcal{K}^{\perp}:=\text{span}(K)^{\perp}$ is involutive(1) , then it means that taking two vector fields $\xi,\eta$ which are orthogonal to $K$ implies their Lie-bracket is also orthogonal to $K$, and hence the second term of $(5)$ drops out, thus leaving us with
\begin{align}
g(\nabla_XV,Y)&=-g(V,X)g(A,Y).
\end{align}
Since $Y$ is arbitrary, this first implies $\nabla_XV=-g(V,X)A$, and so by arbitrariness of $X$, it follows $\nabla V=-g(V,\cdot)A$, i.e in index notation, this is the claimed result $\nabla_bV^a=-V_bA^a$.

Summary.
As a ‘higher-level’/more ‘conceptual’ summary, we have:

for any vector field $Z$, we can view $\nabla Z$ as an endomorphism $TM\to TM$. We can then give it a $2\times 2$ block decomposition relative to $TM=\mathcal{K}\oplus\mathcal{K}^{\perp}$, namely $\nabla Z=\begin{pmatrix}
(\nabla Z)|_{\mathcal{K},\mathcal{K}}& 
(\nabla Z)|_{\mathcal{K}^{\perp},\mathcal{K}}\\
(\nabla Z)|_{\mathcal{K},\mathcal{K}^{\perp}}&
(\nabla Z)|_{\mathcal{K}^{\perp},\mathcal{K}^{\perp}}
\end{pmatrix}$.

$V$ is normalized, so $\nabla V$ has values orthogonal to $V$ (equation (1)), and so the block-decomposition simplifies to
$\nabla V=\begin{pmatrix}
0& 
0\\
(\nabla V)|_{\mathcal{K},\mathcal{K}^{\perp}}&
(\nabla V)|_{\mathcal{K}^{\perp},\mathcal{K}^{\perp}}
\end{pmatrix}$ (this was expressed in a more explicit and ugly manner in $(2)$). Our task is to determine these bottom two bundle homomorphisms.

$K$ is Killing, so $\nabla K$ is skew-adjoint, meaning the block decomposition is of the form
$\nabla K=\begin{pmatrix}
(\nabla K)|_{\mathcal{K},\mathcal{K}}& 
-T^*\\
T&
(\nabla K)|_{\mathcal{K}^{\perp},\mathcal{K}^{\perp}}
\end{pmatrix}$, with these diagonal entries being skew-adjoint endomorphisms of $\mathcal{K},\mathcal{K}^{\perp}$ respectively. Since $\mathcal{K}^{\perp}$ is assumed to be involutive, it follows (by $(4)$) that bottom right endomorphism $(\nabla K)|_{\mathcal{K}^{\perp},\mathcal{K}^{\perp}}$ is not merely skew-adjoint, but in fact vanishes identically. Also, since $\mathcal{K}$ has 1-dimensional fibers, it follows the top left endomorphism vanishes as well. Hence, the block decomposition simplifies to
$\nabla K=\begin{pmatrix}0& -T^*\\
T&0
\end{pmatrix}$
with $T:=(\nabla K)|_{\mathcal{K},\mathcal{K}^{\perp}}$.

Combining the above two statements and using the product rule for $V=\frac{K}{f}$ shows (see $(3)$) that the bottom right endomorphism of $\nabla V$, i.e $(\nabla V)|_{\mathcal{K}^{\perp},\mathcal{K}^{\perp}}$ vanishes identically. Therefore, only $(\nabla V)|_{\mathcal{K},\mathcal{K}^{\perp}}$ remains.

Since $\mathcal{K}$ is a line bundle spanned by the unit vector $V$, it follows that knowledge of $\nabla_VV$ determines $\nabla V$ entirely. Thus, we get the formula $\nabla_{(\cdot)} V=-g(V,\cdot)\nabla_VV\equiv-g(V,\cdot)A$, where the minus sign is because $V$ is unit timelike.



Proof of $A=\frac{\text{grad}(f)}{f}$.
You didn’t really ask for this, but let me present it for the sake of completeness. We have $f^2=-g(K,K)=-K^bK_b$. So, differentiating gives
\begin{align}
2f\nabla^af=-2(\nabla^aK^b)K_b=2(\nabla^bK^a)K_b=2(\nabla_KK)^a,
\end{align}
where the second equality used that $K$ is Killing. Hence, dividing by $2f$ gives $\text{grad}(f)=\nabla_VK$. In particular, we have $\nabla_Vf=g(\text{grad}(f),V)=g(\nabla_VK,V)=0$, since $K$ being Killing implies $\nabla K$ is skew-adjoint. So,
\begin{align}
A&=\nabla_VV=-\frac{\nabla_Vf}{f^2}K+\frac{\nabla_VK}{f}=0+\frac{\text{grad}(f)}{f},
\end{align}
i.e $A^a=\frac{\nabla^af}{f}$.

(1) Technically speaking, if you directly assume, as Hawking and Ellis state, that $K$ is orthogonal to a family of hypersurfaces, then the fact that $[\xi,\eta]$ is orthogonal to $K$ is actually the easy half of Frobenius’ theorem (i.e integrability $\implies$ involutivity is the easy half). In this calculation, if we instead merely assume the subbundle $\mathcal{K}^{\perp}$ is involutive, then the second term of $(5)$ drops out by definition. So, actually, we never have to invoke the hard part of Frobenius’ theorem (that involutivity $\implies$ integrability) in this little calculation.


Yes! Yes! Yes! Hawking and Ellis mentioned “a static metric” at the beginning, so hypersurface orthogonality is necessary, I overlooked it. Thank you!
